# ¿Como conectarse a un servidor sql sin dejar expuestas las credenciales de usuario en el código de la aplicación?

Tags: python, sql-server

tengo una aplicaciones en Python que hace consultas a una base de datos SQL server, para ello tengo una función que hace la conexión con el servidor, pero esta aplicación la voy a compartir a alguien mas y el puede ver el código de la aplicación, no quiero que el vea las credenciales de acceso al servidor SQL ,para esto use la clase **cryptography** y encripte en un archivo la cadena de conexión y se crea un archivo con la clave para desencriptar, pero al momento de hacer la conexión por fuerza el archivo se desencripta y con solo modificar unas líneas de código se puede guardar la cadena desencriptada e imprimirla en consola.

aquí se desencripta la cadena

```
def decrypt():
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

with open('clave.key', 'rb') as archivo_clave:
    clave = archivo_clave.read()

with open('cadena_conexion.encrypted', 'rb') as archivo_conexion:
    cadena_conexion_encriptada = archivo_conexion.read()

cipher_suite = Fernet(clave)
cadena_conexion = cipher_suite.decrypt(cadena_conexion_encriptada).decode()
return cadena_conexion
```

en ese codigo con tan solo poner un **print(cadena_conexion)** ya se pueden ver las credenciales.

mi consulta es hay alguna manera de hacer la conexión con la base de datos sin colocar las credenciales dentro del código de la aplicación. y como se hace?
gracias!

Comment: Entonces no le des un superusuario. Crea desde SQL Server un usuario con privilegios limitados a las tablas que debe consultar y si solo va a hacer SELECT, pues le das solo ese permiso o incluso una vista con los datos necesarios.

Comment: Otra cosa.. nunca deberia conectarse a tu base de datos directamente desde tu programa.. deberia conectarse a una api que entre a tu db y le devuelva lo que necesita...

Comment: Así puedes correr el pgma contra otras BBDD (una de prueba, por ejemplo).